# AWS EC2 instance Django project

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

my website is not connecting AWS EC2 instance, gunicorn, nginx giving positive response,security group had allowed HTTP,HTTPS

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iODKc.png




[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3GgG.png

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5D5.png
```

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emvci.png)

```
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lQGM.png
```

Comment: Does `curl localhost` work?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your instance firewall is blocking the connection

You can enable connection to port 80 by running:

```
sudo ufw allow http
```